# Microsoft work and personal accounts same email address

Tags: office365, microsoft-onenote

Before signing up for a office 365 business account through my work, we were using personal Microsoft accounts for things like OneNote. Unfortunately now that we have made the switch to a work account and registered our domain, we cannot create personal accounts using the @domain.com emails. Which would be fine except we have a lot of OneNote notebooks setup on personal accounts.

The users that had personal accounts before the switch now have a personal and work account associated with their email, however, new users cannot get a personal account setup with their email address (which we want to keep as being a work address so we can control the account)

Is there a way to create a personal Microsoft account even though there is a work account associated to the domain?

Comment: Not without using something other than Office 365 for email. Another approach would be to create another domain with email *not* hosted by Office 365. If you want to get fancy, it can still be in your work domain, for example `someone@email.yourdomain.com`